# What CSS is used by browsers for styling invalid <input type="email">s?

Tags: css, forms, html, webforms

OK, so in HTML5 browsers you can have:

```
<input class="txt-box" type="email" name="email" rel="required" />
```

When the email is not in the proper format it puts a red box around it.

My question is: what is the CSS that determines that style?

Comment: Thanks @Paul, wasn't sure how to word the question.

Comment: here is the URL:http://jasonspickdesign.com/contact.php

Comment: you’re very welcome, not sure if I made it much clearer, it’s one of those tricky ones.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depends on the browser. This should cover your bases:

```
input:invalid, input:-moz-ui-invalid {
    border:0;
    outline:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    -moz-box-shadow:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none;
}
```

Test out the effect in a compliant browser:

```
input[type="email"] {
    border:0;
    outline:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

IE7 compliance would require:

```
input.txt-box {
    border:0 !important;
    outline:none !important;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3Ainvalid

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/cUgW4/

Comment: that would style its default state...not its invalid state.

Comment: Correct, although I didn't know you could select forms fields like that I'll vote you up one for that. Still need to figure out invalid state.

Comment: yeah, that didn't do anything. firbug shows the style I added, but the red outline is still there.

Comment: I'm not seeing it bro, even on Firefox 2. What browser are you using to test?

Comment: @Paul yea FF5 is HTML5 compliant so `input type="email"` would not render as invalid. Check out [Spoon browsers](http://www.spoon.net/browsers) for legacy browser testing.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: I think when Jason says “invalid”, he means the styling that browsers like Firefox 5 use when you enter an invalid e-mail address into an `<input type="email">`.

Comment: Ahhh I see it now - yea ok It's the box-shadow property. See updated code.

Comment: `:invalid` is different from `:-moz-ui-invalid`, in Firefox at least. The former applies the styling **immediately** as soon as the page loads. The latter waits until the user has entered something invalid. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-ui-invalid#Summary.

Answer (score 7):

If you install the Firebug extension in Firefox and use it to inspect the form field in question, you’ll be able to see the CSS that Firefox uses internally to style it. (Make sure “Show User Agent CSS” is ticked in the Style tab’s pop-up menu.)

In Firefox 5 on my Mac, it uses the following CSS:

```
:-moz-ui-invalid:not(output) {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.5px 1px red;
}
```

Interesting they use `box-shadow`. There was a question on Stack Overflow I saw recently that mentioned the `:-moz-ui-invalid` selector: see [Style HTML5 input types if validation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911175/style-html5-input-types-if-validation-fails/6911248#6911248).