# How to correctly clear a form in React avoiding a red border in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, forms, firefox

In my web app https://tahdo.app/ I have three (required) inputs. Once all 3 input are filled out and the user presses the "Add" button (or hits enter), the form is cleared and the focus resets to the first input.
However, in Firefox, all 3 inputs will now how a red border as Firefox thinks they are invalid.
I assume that means that I am not clearing the form in the correct React-way.
How should I be clearing the form to avoid these red boxes?

Comment: Nothing to do with React probably. You have to disable the browser's native validation. Add a `novalidate` attribute to the form and manage validation on your own

Comment: There's no way to reset the validation state of the form?
I'm sure I had an Angular app that did a similar thing that worked fine in FF.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a JavaScript API for this. You can play with css and `:invalid` selector (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915200/what-css-is-used-by-browsers-for-styling-invalid-input-type-emails)

Comment: Angular also had the same problem but overrode it as part of the framework somehow. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12102
My solution was to remove the incorrect styling from Firefox:
`:-moz-ui-invalid { box-shadow: none; }`
Thanks for the suggestions.